# Minimize the cost of travel for truck driving.

Tags: calculus, optimization, word-problem

A truck has a min. speed of $9mph$ in the highest gear. When traveling $x$ mph, the truck burns diesel fuel at a rate:

$0.0224868((1156/x) + x)$ gal/mile

The truck can not be driven over $51mph$ and the diesel fuel costs $1.44 gal, find the following.

(a) The steady speed that will minimize the cost of diesel fuel for a 470 mile trip.

The answer for (a) is 34 mile/hour, this is the min. of the function above found via the Extreme Value Theorem.

***This is where I am having trouble:***

(b) Find the steady speed that will minimize the cost of a 470 mile trip when the driver is being paid $17/hour.

- I have found out that total cost = (cost of the driver) + (cost of fuel for the trip)

I have yet to put any real work behind this because I am lost and I do not know where to start to figure this problem out. I could try a bunch of values, but that would not work and take so long. I thought about making the bounds [34, 51] and somehow finding the inflection point on that, but I do not believe that would work.

I'd appreciate some help with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What truck has min. speed of 9 mph in the highest gear?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone the one out in my yard that hasn't been started in 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem so I'll give my thoughts on it. Suppose we have a truck that has a minimum speed of $v_{\min}$, a maximum speed of $v_\max$, and when moving at a rate $v$ consumes gas at a rate $g(v)$ gallons per mile, as in the question, although gallons per hour would be a more realistic measure. Say that the fuel costs $c$ dollars per gallon, the driver is paid $p$ dollars per hour, and we want to minimize the cost of traveling $d$ miles. Assuming we pick a **constant** velocity $v$ to travel the entire trip, here is how we compute the total cost $C(v)$:

The amount of gas consumed will be the distance of the journey in miles multiplied by the amount of fuel consumed per mile, that is
$$\text{gas consumed}=d\cdot g(v) \text{ (gallons)}$$
Then, using the cost of gas per gallon:
$$\text{cost of gas}=d\cdot g(v)\cdot c\text{ (dollars)}$$
Now we need to determine the amount the driver is paid for the trip, which is his hourly rate multiplied by the number of hours the trip takes.
$$\text{driver pay}=p\cdot \frac{d}{v}\text{ (dollars)}$$
The total cost is the sum of these two. Hence,
$$C(v)=d\left(c\cdot g(v)+\frac{p}{v}\right)$$
Minimizing this function in the interval $[v_\min , v_\max]$ with respect to $v$ will give the answer.

Comment: Using the function $g(v)=0.0224868\left(\frac{1156}{v}+v\right)$, $d=470$, $c=1.44$, and $p=17$ I found a minimum of $ \$ 1247.96 $ at $v=41\text{mph}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you solved 1), solving 2) isn't much harder.
Just express the cost of the driver as a function of the distance and the speed $x$. Then solve the problem using the same technique as 1).

Comment: How exactly would I set that up? C(x) = the function + cost*hours.

Comment: You have the hourly price. So you need to find the duration of the trip, given the speed and the distance.